# Getting a color with same tint, but of another color?

Tags: css, colors

In my CSS, I defined the `#error` div as:

```
#error {
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color: #DD3C10;
    background:#FFEBE8;
    /* Other settings */
}
```

The code above isn't mine, actually - I used the same colors as Facebook. Now, I want to do the same with the `#success` div, but I don't know which colors to use. I want to keep the same tint (which is, the position on the line between "full color" and "white"), but of green instead of red. How do I do it? Is there a "formula"?

Comment: This is one of the reasons chrome dev tools were created. border-color: #10DD18;
background: #EEFFE8; No formula to be found anywhere just eyeball it. Not even in rgb: border-color: rgb(16, 221, 24);
background: rgb(238, 255, 232);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You care about the L (lightness) component in the HSL representation of your color. You can find an online converter (RGB/HEX to HSL) here: [little link](http://serennu.com/colour/hsltorgb.php).

HSL for `#DD3C10` is `13° 86% 46%`, while `#FFEBE8` is `8° 100% 95%`. Difference in lightness is, as you see, `49%`.

Suppose your green for `border` is `#00FF00`, which is `120° 100% 50%` in HSL. To calculate the new lightness component, just add `49%`. Thus the green for `background` is `120° 100% 99%` which is `#FAFFFA`.

Comment: HSL: 13° 86% 23% RGB: 109 30 8 Hex: #6D1E08 vs HSL: 8° 100% 95% RGB: 255 235 232 Hex: #FFEBE8. Still can't see your point as the originals have difference in saturation and hue.

Comment: LESS and other CSS pre-processors allow for this type of thing inline :)

Answer (score 0):

There sure is an easy way. Just use the HSL colour system, instead of RGB - it's much more intuitive to use to select the desired colour, it's the colour-system of choice to use when tinting an image.

All you then have to do is express the base colour as a HSL colour, then just change the Saturation or the Luminance, while leaving the Hue the same.

E.g

- borderCol = #DD3C10; (rgb) ---- hsl(13,93%,87%)
- background = #FFEBE8; (rgb) --- hsl(8,9%,100%)

new

- borderCol = #49DD10; (rgb) ---- hsl(103,93%,87%)
- background = #f0ffe8; (rgb) --- hsl(98,9%,100%)